# What is the meaning of "if anything"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I do understand the meaning of "if anything" in the context. I can understand each word individually.

Here is the text:

> In the past it was a common belief that snakes couldn't hear much, **if anything**, since they have no external ears and don't seem to respond much to noises. However, some scientific research refutes this common misconception.

I feel like the text is understandable without saying "if anything" so why does the writer put it in the text?

Comment: It's just the emphasis : "if they (snakes ) could hear anything at all."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If anything** is a an idiom used to describe a very small amount of *something*.

> **if anything** *(at all)*
>   **if** *(there is)* **anything**
>
> The price of the book, **if anything**, is a dollar.
>   That city, **if anything**, is a nice place to visit.

A similar phrase

> **if nothing else**

has the same meaning as **if** *(there is)* **anything**

> That city, **if nothing else**, is a nice place to visit.

Answer (score 4):

V.V's comment is correct. "If anything" is mostly being used for *emphasis*. It restates what's already clearly stated (as having been believed): that snakes can hear very little. However, it does so by opening up the possibilities a bit, implying it's possible that some snakes can't hear at all.

It can be removed without changing the meaning significantly.